# Closures and random numbers in F#

Tags: random, f#, closures

For fun, I am trying to write a simple simulation of the
[Monty Hall problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem)
 problem using F#.

I have created a function *getShow* which returns an array of three booleans (representing doors), one of which is randomly true (it has a car behind it) and the other two false.

```
let getShow = 
    let doorWithCar = System.Random().Next(3)+1
    [|for door in 1..3 -> door = doorWithCar|]
```

Now when I try to get a sequence of shows using *yield* to call the *getShow* function, I keep getting the first random show repeated (I am guessing because of the way closures work in F#).

```
let shows = 
  seq { for i in 1 .. 10 do yield getShow} // Keeps generating the same show over and over
```

What is the correct way to call the *getShow* function using *yield* so that it actually calls the function and gets a new random array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getShow` is a value and not a function, so it's calculated once and you keep yielding the same value. To turn it into a function you have to add `()`. Also, you keep creating a new `Random` instance, which is probably initialized with the same time seed, not giving you what you want. Try this instead:

```
let random = System.Random()
let getShow() = 
    let doorWithCar = random.Next(3)+1
    [|for door in 1..3 -> door = doorWithCar|]
let shows = 
   seq { for i in 1 .. 10 do yield getShow()}
```